# How to create vertical navigation bar in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image]

Im working on my school project, Windows forms app.

As u see, i create 3 panels, one for header, one for nav bar, and one for content. Can i meake header and nav bar static, like layout in webpages, and change content on btn click.

I do it creating a few panels, and change visibility (true/false) for every panel to show specific one. Is there better whay to do this, i think it has to be more elegant, im beginer, its school project and im finding for clever answer.

Answer (score 10):

Surely there are many options for creating such layout in windows forms. Here I share some good options for Vertical Menu, Center Container and Content Holder.

**Vertical Menu**

You have many options including these 2 good options:

- `ToolStrip` component which its `Dock` property  set to `Left`. Also items of the menu can have images, and you can set to show images before text or above text. You can make one item checked on click and uncheck other items. This way it's obvious which one is active menu.
- `Panel` control containing some `RadioButton` controls. The `Dock` property of panel is set to `Left` and it contains some `RadionButton` controls which you set its `Appearance` to `Button` and its `Dock` property of them to `Top`. You can set the `FlatAppearance` of radio buttons to `System` or `Flat`. Also radio buttons can show images before or above text.

**Center Container**

You can use a `Panel` as container. Set `Dock` property of the container panel to `Fill`.

**Content Holder**

Like menu, you have many options including these 2 good options:

- You can use different `TabPages` of a `TabControl` as content holders. Put different contents in different tab of the control. You can hide tab headers and also you can disable shortcut keys which makes navigation between tabs. Then it's enough to set selected tab of the control based on selected menu.
- You can use different `Form`s as content holders. Put different contents in different forms. Then you can show a form in the content panel based on selected menu. To show a form in content panel, it's enough to set `TopLevel` property of forms to false and set `FormBorderStyle` of them to `None` and the add them to center container controls collection and show the form. You can show and hide forms based on selected menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use`FlowLayoutPanel` instead of `Panel` and then just add Menu Item blocks to it.

If you give the menu Item proper width considering the FlowLayoutPanel width, you will get the menu you want.