# design backstageview control in C# without using WPF

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, devexpress, navigationbar

I want to design a navigation bar like backstageview which devexpress implement it.

You can see sample of it in [link1](https://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/i/15.2/win10apps-hamburger-control-15-2.png)

[image: https://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/i/15.2/win10apps-hamburger-control-15-2.png]

and [link2](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Silverlight/Ribbon/i/features/DXRibbon-BackstageView-2013.png)

[image]

I read it is possible by a listbox and some panels which by clicking on every item, one panel be active and its bringfront() event is called. But I don't know how listbox can displayed like backstageview.
If you have other way for designing backstageview, please explain it.

Comment: Why don't use DevExpress **WinForms** BackstageView?

Comment: As an option you may find this post helpful: [How to create vertical navigation bar in Windows Forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243690/how-to-create-vertical-navigation-bar-in-windows-forms)

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten: how can I change back color of backstageviewItem? I change backcolor and backcolor2, but nothing change.

Comment: @manizheh, do you need to have it black?

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten: No, I am not certain about color;But it is possible I select blue. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Well, @manizheh is the issue resolved by using DevExpress WinForms BackstageView?

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten: yes,I am using DevExpress WinForms BackstageView.

Comment: @manizheh, thank you for your clarification. I've moved my comment to an answer to this thread so that you can approve it and close this thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118059/discussion-between-manizheh-and-gosha-fighten).

Answer (score 0):

Use the DevExpress WinForms [BackStageview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsRibbonBackstageViewControltopic) for your task.