# How to add multiple tabs or pages in Win forms Application

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: Link to the Image:]

This is UI of the app which I'm creating, So if a user clicks `Home` button he should be able to play with some specific controls and again if he presses `Sellers` button, new tools and controls should be visible on the screen!

I tried to implement this by using 4 panels with

```
panel_name.visible=false
```

in respective button click event, but the problem is each panel should take up 1/4th of the space in the form to display all of its respective tools.This makes the panel area too small!

How can I make the application such that If a user clicks `Home` button, he should see one page/tab and different tabs/pages for different buttons clicks?

Comment: Have you considered using a [TabControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @stuartd Yes, I did! but I cannot insert icons on the tab heading and all the tab headings are stitched to one another and they're horizontally aligned! Can I make them vertically aligned?

Comment: [How to create vertical navigation bar in Windows Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36243690/3110834)

Comment: @DheerajN I'll explain how to use user controls, do you use Twitter?

Comment: @DheerajN Ready, I followed you, follow me to start

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use WPF or UWP?

Comment: @RonBeyer Simply Winforms is easier than WPF or WUP

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán Not really, this type of thing would be trivially easy in WPF, in WinForms it requires some manipulation of paint events and the fun issues you get with that. I've been a Winforms developer since 2002, and a lot of things are much harder in WInforms than XAML.

Comment: @RonBeyer But is it easier only in terms of aesthetics?

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán No, not a discussion for here though, I find it is easier to use in just about every way from data binding/code behind and animation to compositing, layout, etc.

Comment: @RonBeyer Well, I started with WPF and it happened to Winfroms because it was easier for me to understand it, and that, I have previous experience of XML design in Android

Comment: @RonBeyer I'm forced to confess that you were right about WPF, it's just better than WinForms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the user controls: right click on your solution> add> user control

[C# UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

[How to create and use UserControl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5L_q_jI494)

The user controls are similar to the forms, since you can place controls on them, the difference is that instead of showing them as common forms, you drag them as a control inside the form

Comment: −1. The video does not show the use case that the OP requires.